# How to charge prorated rate on paypal subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Trying to set up a subscription via paypal rest API. I am looking on a solution on how to modify the subscription and charge the specific fee in 1 checkout. I found a way to change the quantity on the subscription, but the problem paypal does not prorate.

So for example, if user subscribes today with 10x of product and then changes the subscription to 20x of product, the paypal will not charge the prorated fee. So how to handle that?

This is an official msg from paypal:
The new price is effective starting on the next billing cycle. Proration and one-time fees aren't automatically supported. If you want to prorate the difference at the time the plan changes or charge one-time fees, you need to do these manually. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/customize/revise-subscriptions/

How do I charge it manually?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I charge it manually?

Use setup_fee to simply add an additional fee, or use a 1 cycle trial period to modify the amount of the first payment, which can be lower or higher.